# apache RewriteRule question

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I want to test for test.com and serve a particular file if I find it anywhere in the request, and if I don't find it move on to the rest of the rules.  I can't get it to consistently do this.

RewriteRule ^/test.com /var/www/html/index.html [NC,L]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  Are you looking to act on requests sent to `test.com`, or ones with `test.com` as part of the file or directory structure in the request?

Answer (score 0):

The ^ means start of line/string, so requests to http://example.com/test.com and https://www.example.com/test.com_with_more should match, but http://example.com/in_front_test.com would not match. Try removing the ^ and prefix the . with a \ so that it matches a . and not any char use

```
RewriteRule test\.com /var/www/html/index.html [NC,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule was used as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's very helpful.  I'm still having an issue with www.test.com vs test.com.  I would think the folliowing would match either, but it doesn't seem to be the case:

RewriteRule test\.com /var/www/html/index.html [NC,L]

Comment: I would think it would work too. Does http://example.com/in_front_test.com work, but not http://example.com/www.test.com?